# Is it possible to get a value from an processing instruction?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

As I asked in my title, is it possible to get a value from an processing instruction?

for example:

```
<root>
<?ConditionState 4?>
</root>
```

I tried many ways to achieve this a result but all I got is nothing...

Here is a way that I tried (Error Case):

```
<root>
    <xsl:value-of select="root[?ConditionState]"></xsl:value-of>
</root>
```

I want to achieve this resault:

```
<root>
    4
</root>
```

Or:

```
<root>
    3
</root>
```

---

I also tried:
`substring-after(substring-before(/root,'?>'),'<?ConditionState ')`
But that doesn't work either.

Comment: No. Element names cannot start with `?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An XML node enclosed within `<?` and `?>` isn't an **element**, it's a **processing instruction** and it can be selected using the `processing-instruction()` node test.

See below:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="processing-instruction('ConditionState')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjin4